# The connection string property has not been initialized

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to search my database using the below code, but I am getting the above error.

```
 Private Sub ButtonSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonSearch.Click

    myConnection.Open()
    Textlocation.Clear()

    Dim str As String
    str = "select * From STUDENTS where ADMINNO like " & "'%" & SearchTextBox.Text & "%'"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
     Textadminac.Text = dr("ADMINNO").ToString
    End While
    myConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: well the exception says it all, doesn't it? - you probably forgot to specify the `ConnectionString` on the `myConnection` variable

Comment: As what @peter has mentioned...I agree. Set a breakpoint on the: myConnection.Open line and press F10, it should blow up there. If so you need to provide the connection string.